# Is a forward declaration inside a class body considered a different type?

Tags: c++, c++11, inner-classes, forward-declaration

I have two inner structs inside an enclosing class and in one of the structs, I have a pointer member to objects of the other struct's type. And to improve readability and make it clear that the forward declaration is intended for the struct that needs it, I put the forward declaration in the inner struct itself. Something like this

```
class Enclosing{
public:
    struct InnerA{
       struct InnerB; // forward declaration inside InnerA to improve readability  
       InnerB* b; 
       // other members
   };

    struct InnerB{

       // lots of member variables
    };
};
```

And then somewhere outside I have a function

```
void DoSomething(){
    Enclosing::InnerA a;


    // error incompatible types Enclosing::InnerB* and Enclosing::InnerA::InnerB*
    Enclosing::InnerB* ptr = a.b; 
}
```

It is to my understanding that forward declarations are only a way to tell the compiler that a class exists, not define a completely different new type. Is this standard? if so, is there a way to have the forward declaration inside the struct without being considered as a different type?

Comment: You can do the forward declaration inside `Enclosing` rather than inside `InnerA`

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. Enclosing is a rather large class and I think it would be more appropriate to have the forward declaration inside the struct that needs it.

Comment: A forward declaration is a declaration that is valid at point of declaration itself. You're asking if you are allowed to declare something in namespace different from the namespace in which the declaration should occur, which is not possible.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is considered a different type.

A declaration places the name into the scope where the declaration appears. Every class introduces its own scope. Thus, in your case, you have `Enclosing::InnerA::InnerB`, which is clearly different from `Enclosing::InnerB`.

I'm afraid there's no way to declare a name in a different scope other than the current one. You'll simply need to declare `InnerB` directly inside of `Enclosing`, before the definition of `InnerA` where it is used.

Answer (score 4):

Your forward declaration is nested twice, you are forward declaring `Enclosing::InnerA::InnerB`, but your definition is for `Enclosing::InnerB` so you are actually forward declaring a different type.

You should remain at same level:

```
class Enclosing {
  struct InnerB;

  struct InnerA {
    InnerB* ptr;
  };
};
```

The problem is not the forward declaration per se, it's like if you were doing:

```
class Enclosing {
  struct InnerA {
    struct InnerB {
      int data;
    };

    InnerB* ptr;
  }; 

  struct InnerB {
    float data;
  };
};
```

You see that `Enclosing::InnerA::InnerB` and `Enclosing::InnerB` are indeed different types, this because the declaration retains it's locality like a normal declaration.